# .Net Remoting for UWP

Tags: c#, .net, service, uwp, .net-core

How to work with the .Net Remoting concepts in UWP. I found an article which has quoted the below text.

This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the  Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e7z38xb(v=vs.100).aspx

Do we have any alternate to achieve the .Net Remoting Concept in UWP?

Comment: Give an example of what you're trying to achieve because there are several techniques used.

Comment: I need a simple text which am typing in the client, it should reflected in the server also.

Comment: That really doesn't help a lot.  This could be done with WebApi, SignalR, TCP, UDP, etc.  I am interested in knowing the entire process and purpose so that I or someone else can help you get the right answer, not just any answer.

Comment: yes I need the remoting should done based on the TCP and UDP

Comment: Ok, I have experience in both on UWP and at first it was a little confusing to me... Only because I was use to the ways of old.  It's changed due to many factors but primarily because UWP requires user permissions, can be frozen at any time (and may need to be passed to a system client layer during that time), is more lightweight for various platforms (so may require more work than usual) etc. Anyway, I'm working but will try to get back to this with example if I can soon. Apologies.

Comment: Ok, I am expecting the solution from you. it will be better to me to understand the remoting concepts.